# Cannot edit pages if another user is already on same page

Tags: page-layout, home-page-layout

If there are other users for editing a page like lead page,they cannot edit the lead page,since there are already users who are already on a page whoa are editing the page

How can this be rectified.

Comment: As in, editing a page layout? I can't imagine this being a problem, since only admins should be doing edits, and should be coordinating their efforts.

Comment: @sfdcfox I guess this is a different story. Say User A and B both opens Lead l1. Let's say User A updated Field f1 to new value and User B updated Field f2. And when User B opens the lead edit page, f1 is off old value when B clicks save button after A did the same thing. f1 value will be overwritten into its old value.

Comment: @LanceShi It's tagged "page-layout", and besides, salesforce does have "[collision detection](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000006771)" that generally prevents B from saving without refreshing the page first in your example.

Comment: @sfdcfox Ah, forgive me for not realizing the tag and thanks for the information.

Comment: @sfdcfox: My apologies for putting the tag randomly. Actually there is a field chat body where two users at same time try to enter the information and they are getting the error

Comment: @kunalgupta You can't defeat collision detection. I believe you may be asking the [wrong question](http://xyproblem.info/), so you might want to simply ask a question that states what you're trying to achieve, what you've tried, and why it doesn't work, rather than asking about a way to defeat a specific mechanism that's meant to protect data.